# $.when() not waiting for ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, concurrency

I have a problem where if I call functions which contain Ajax calls and return the result of those calls the caller always receives a null return value before the Ajax call has returned.

Example fiddle: [ajax null return value example](http://jsfiddle.net/yp0goac2/)

```
var returnVal;

$.when(fun()).done(function(a1)
{
   console.log("finished ajax");
   returnVal = a1;
});

alert(returnVal);

function fun() {
    $.ajax({//this ajax call should return an ip
        url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("fun(id) ajax success");
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `fun` doesn't return anything so `when` is waiting on `undefined`.  Add a return statement.

Comment: adding a return doesn't fix it, when returns immediately a null without waiting for ajax to complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must return the deferred given by `$.ajax` :

```
function fun() {
    return $.ajax({//this ajax call should return an ip
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to explain why your callback is executed :

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a
>   Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and
>   any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately

There's another problem in your code : you're alerting before the asynchronous call is done. You should move the `alert` inside the callback.

And there's no reason to have a success function, you handle the result in your `done` callback.

You can't really `alert` an object and get something meaningful. You should either do `alert(JSON.stringify(returnVal))` or use `console.log` (less painful anyway, hit F12 to show the console).

```
$.when(fun()).done(function(a1){
    console.log("finished ajax");
    var returnVal = a1;
    console.log(returnVal);
});


function fun() {
    return $.ajax({//this ajax call should return an ip
        url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `$.ajax(...)` returns a deferred. `$.ajax(...).promise()` will return a promise.

Comment: @saimiris_devel There were other bugs in your code, please read the updated answer.

Comment: This answer just saved me after two-hours of struggling. Was only missing the 'return' in my deferred method. Thanks!